# Have Christians ever followed Leviticus?

Tags: leviticus

Has there ever been a group, or groups, of Christians that tried to follow Leviticus (not just parts of it, but all of it or most of it)?

Alternatively, what groups (Christian or otherwise) did try to follow Leviticus?

Apparently the typical view is that there is a new covenant or etc, but were there atypical Christians that tried to follow the old rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paul Upholds and Teaches the Torah Law](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24825/paul-upholds-and-teaches-the-torah-law)

Comment: There are some hangups to completely following Levitical law (one of them being that Israel as a theocracy no longer exists, and the fact that the temple/tabernacle has been destroyed, the ark has been lost), however there are some groups who still follow some of the law (see Messianic Jews). However these groups generally only believe the parts of the Levitical law they follow only applies to Jewish Christians, not to Gentile Christians as this is consistent with the teachings of the Apostles in Acts.

Comment: In other words, asking about whether or not Christians follow Levitical law generally belies a lack of understanding of what Christ's death means and how Christians view the purpose of Levitical law.

Comment: @waxeagle I figured the answer would be "No, you're thinking of it the wrong way info info info", but those are the best answers anyways.

Comment: @Strilanc if you're looking for more info on that route, might I suggest: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30/how-is-ignoring-clear-biblical-instructions-in-leviticus-justified/40#40

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to questions asking "Are there any Christians that do such-and-such" it's very hard to answer, because Christianity is a very diverse group and there are highly likely to be at least a few Christians that do almost anything. However in this case I'm going to go out on a limb and answer "No". Here are my reasons.

1. The first part of Leviticus deals with animal sacrifice. Not just occasional sacrifice, but regular and frequent. It's unlikely that Christians would be doing this without us having heard about it. Even Jews have not followed the sacrifice rules in Leviticus since around 70AD. Additionally it is explicitly taught in Christian scripture that Christ's sacrifice has made animal sacrifices unnecessary. **It's a key part of Christianity not to make the Levitical sacrifices.**
2. A later part of Leviticus deals with clean and unclean food. Again Christians were explicitly told by God (as recorded in Acts 10) not to follow those rules.

There are Christians who spend most of their time interacting with the Jewish community, and some of them follow the dietary rules of Judaism, to avoid giving offence. That's approved of in scripture. However even they will not follow the animal sacrifice rules.

Summary: **I'm pretty confident in being able to answer "no".**

Comment: There are also some groups who specifically interpret some of the things in Acts as applying differently to Jewish Christians and Gentile Christians. So they'll keep Kosher because they believe it still applies to them.